# Unable to generate datapoint series for android graph view line graph

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

I am trying to add multiple data series to an android graph view linegraph - I am using the example from the real-time example as follows:

```
private DataPoint[] generateData() {
        int count = 30;
        DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[count];
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            double x = i;
            double y = Math.sin(i*0.45+2) + 0.3;
            DataPoint v = new DataPoint(x, y);
            values[i] = v;
        }
        return values;
    }
```

and I am adding with the following:

```
series1 = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(generateData());
            graph.addSeries(series1);
```

however when I run this I get an NPE.
Does anyone know what I am missing or doing wrong. I have removed the actual data from the generateData method to ensure that was not the problem. 
Any help will be much appreciated.
Jack

Comment: Thanks - even tho I have declared it earlier in the program? GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

Comment: `findViewById` returns also `null`

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but how to I go about this then?

Comment: post the NPE - logs from logcat

Comment: I have found that redefining the graph immediately before calling the method stops the error and the app works as expected. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1):

```
     values = new DataPoint[10];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            Integer xi = i;
            Integer yi = i+1;
            DataPoint v = new DataPoint(xi, yi);
            values[i] = v;
        }
     series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(values);

     graphView.addSeries(series);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added something like
     `<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="200dip"
     android:id="@+id/graph" />`
to the activity's layout.If not, than add it to the activity's layout
This is where the graph is plotted.You can also change the width,height and other attributes from xml.